# General advice on flight simulator hardware

Tags: flight-simulator

I am new to flying and have only had a couple of lessons in a Cesna 152 but want to get some practice on a simulator as I'm quite old and don't learn quickly compared to youngsters. My instructor wasn't too forthcoming but mentioned that the Microsoft flight simulator was the best software if I wanted to get some practice of that type. I believe I would also need a flight yoke system for a Cesna 152 however am concerned that I don’t waste my money on wrong kit. I believe I would need in addition to the software  a yoke , instrument panel and rudder controls.  I appreciate that its no substitute for practical flying hours but with current lock down under COVID being strictly enforced where I am there is no chance of getting into a plane in the next few months. Please can you   advise suitable products with any links. I have also seen some ads for VR headgear would that also help me?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site @oldboy. I was an avid MS Flight Simulator fan before I did the real thing, and my opinion is it doesn't teach the right sort of lessons. Flying an airplane is easy, the trick is learning how to aviate, navigate and communicate at the same time, and PC simulators don't really help with that. Fast isn't always good, so go at the pace that is right for you, and enjoy the experience!

Comment: I learn to fly at 19yrs in1975 but didn't get a jet type rating until my mid 50s, in an extremely intense type course. My observation was, the old fart learns the physical easily, but struggles with memorizing data.The youngster is the opposite (clumsy teenagers).At this stage, concentrate your time on memorizing data, procedures etc and drill them to death.Learn the physical skills first in the plane.Use the computer sim (FS is great for this) to hone a procedural skill you've learned to do correctly. The biggest downside to home sims is the ability to teach yourself/reinforce the wrong thing